# async in node.js. How to use parallel when each async task itself needs callbacks to get its result?

Tags: node.js, async.js

I understand async.parallel([function1, function2], finalCallback) when function1 and function2 are synchronous functions which each takes a known time or known number of sequential steps.

How about results of function1 and function2 are only available through callbacks?

```
var function1 = doSomething(parameters, function(err, results){
}); 
var function2 = doSomethingElse(parameters, function(err, results){
});
```

How can I use async to make sure that I got results from function1 and function2 within their respectively callbacks before calling finalCallback?

Answer (score 0):

```
var function1 = function(cb) {
  doSomething(parameters, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
      cb(err);
    } else {
      console.log('YAY, do something happened');
      cb(null, results);
    }
  });
};
```